# Check out without payment

Tags: checkout

I am not a developer. We have a client who wishes customers to order via a Magento 2 website we have implemented but wishes to bill them for payment offline. How is this best achieved in terms of the customer check-out once they have their order in their cart? Many, many thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 has some offline payment methods, for example - **Cash on delivery, Check/Money Order**. You can use them or create a similar new.

Comment: Thank you for your response - much appreciated. Where are these offline payment selections found - within Products ??

Comment: you can find them at Store->Configuration then Sales->Payment method

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind advice - very grateful

Comment: Thank you so much again, we get as far as 'Place Order': next we get internal error. In plesk, in folder : httpdocs>var>log>exeption.log 2 and execption.log   :  we find nothing inn todays date. (that is where it should be, but it isn’t)   Can’t find the log. If we can share your email, we can provide screenshot & perhaps agree an arrangement for your help. Thank you again, you are very kind.